# Delphi 7 and .dfm files get the forms displayed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windows-7-x64

I'm a beginner. I have received a `.rar` file containing a bunch of files. I think that they are used to generate Forms.

Here's an example:

- BackupManager.dfm
- BackupManager.pas
- WaveControl.dfm
- WaveControl.pas

So, can anyone help me understand exactly how to use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `.dfm` file contains the property values and sub object definitions of a  Form.  The `.pas` file that has the same base filename as the `.dfm` file contains the Delphi Pascal source code for the Form, its event handlers, etc.

To use these files, simply create a Delphi VCL Forms project and add the `.pas` files to the project.  Each `.pas` file should have a `{$R *.dfm}` compiler directive in it to link to its associated `.dfm` file.

The compiler will compile each `.pas` file into a `.dcu` file and link it into the final executable, and will also create a separate binary resource for the content of each `.dfm` file and link them into the executable as well.

When the executable is run and it tries to create an instance of a Form class (either automatically at startup, or explicitly in code), the RTL will automatically load the appropriate DFM resource and parse it to construct the necessary sub objects, assign their property values, and hook up their event handlers.